# Converting Celsius to Fahrenheit, kelvin and Rankine

Tags: html, select, text, parseint

The user will input a celsius value, then he/she will choose from a drop down list the temperature scale he/she would like to convert it to. then when the user clicks a button, the result will appear in a second text box. I've tried doing it but so far I can't even get the result to be printed in the last text box. here is my code:

```
<body>
<form name=myForm>  
    <p> Celcius Value

        <input type="text" name="celcius" />

    <p> Convert to

        <select name="to" id="to">

            <option></optio>
            <option value="Farenheit"> Farenheit</option>
            <option value="Kelvin"> Kelvin</option>
            <option value="Rankine"> Rankine</option>
        </select>

    <hr size=2 color="blue">

    <p> Click this to convert <button onclick="Converter()" />Convert</button>

    <p> Result <input type="text" id="result" />

    <script>

        fucntion Converter() {

            var celcius = document.myForm.celcius.value;

            var sel = document.getEleemntById("to");
            var selVal = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

            if (selVal == "Farenheit") {

                var result = (parseInt(celcius)*(9/5.0)) +32;

            }else if ( selVal == "Kelvin") {

                var result = parseInt(celcius)+273.15;

            }else { 
                var result = (parseInt(celcius)+273.15)* (9/5.0);

            }

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= result;
        }
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

Could you kind hearted people please check what's wrong with it?

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser (e.g. by pressing F12) and you would see many starting points for fixing the errors. There's an obvious typo at the 2nd non-empty line in your `Converter` function.

Comment: there is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code review

Comment: I'm new to this whole javascript thing...I don't actually know how to find the error even when i opened the developer tool

Comment: `fucntion` -> `function`

Answer (score 1):

You should try jslint - it can find your javascript errors:

```
function Converter() {

        var celcius = document.myForm.celcius.value;

        var sel = document.getElementById("to");
        var selVal = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selVal == "Farenheit") {

            var result = (parseInt(celcius)*(9/5.0)) +32;

        }else if ( selVal == "Kelvin") {

            var result = parseInt(celcius)+273.15;

        }else { 
            var result = (parseInt(celcius)+273.15)* (9/5.0);

        }

        document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
```

Comment: It says Unexpected '<' in line 1 character 1 , but i don't understand, it's just <html>